# Java JBDC connector

Tags: java, mysql, mysqlconnector

Среда разработки

```
intellij idea community
```

Мне нужно работать с БД mySQL. Т.к. версия у меня community, мне пришлось качать плагин

```
DB Navigator
```

Теперь я пишу код

```
import java.sql.*;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Connection connection;

        try {
            Driver driver = FabricMySQLDriver();

        }
        catch (SQLException se) {
            System.out.println("Ошибка загрузки драйвера");
        }

    }
}
```

и строка `FabricMySQLDriver`выделяется красным. Судя по гуглу, этот код устарел и нужен другой. Помогите разобраться или дайте ссылку на материал.

Comment: Как минимум, нужно заменить `FabricMySQLDriver` на `new FabricMySQLDriver()`. А вообще, как вариант, можете попробовать способ, описанный в [этой](https://tproger.ru/translations/java-jdbc-example/) статье.

Comment: FabricMySQLDriver опечатка (исправил). IDEA не понимает этого кода

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы подключиться к бд, нужно использовать [DriverManager.getConnection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html#getConnection(java.lang.String)).

Пример использования:

```
import java.sql.*;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:...");
        }
        catch (SQLException se) {
             System.out.println("Ошибка загрузки драйвера");
        }
    }
}
```

Так же для того, чтобы работать с J**D**BC вам не нужно ни IntelJ Idea, ни никаких плагинов.

Пример JDBC ссылки: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/

Если вы все же хотите работать напрямую с драйверами, тогда у вас две проблемы:

1. У вас нет нужной библиотеки
2. У вас не подключен нужный класс файл.

Comment: Не могли бы вы мне обьяснить по поводу установки драйвера. Мне нужно скачать jar. и положить его в корневой каталог проекта?

Comment: Да, скачать нужно его. Но его нужно прикрепить к проекту как библиотеку. Для упрощения жизни программистам есть gradle. Он может сам за вас: 1. скачать 2. скомпилировать 3. сделать готовый проект идеи. Так же вам нужен наверное-что не fabric драйвер, а простой. MySQL Fabric для кластеров.

Comment: драйвер победил. Коннект есть но выдает предупреждение Sun Nov 20 00:07:53 EAT 2016 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.

Comment: Если вы не собираетесь использовать SSL подключение с вашей базой данных, можете дописать до ссылки ?useSSL=false. Если все же хотите настроить SSL, для этого есть хороший и оффициальный туториал https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-using-ssl.html